# Double Menu Fixed on Animated Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to made an double animated scroll menu.. I mean, my design have 2 menu. 1 top menu and another page menu. when I scroll both menu will fixed on top. like my screenshot.

[image: I want both menu fixed when scroll like that]

When I click overview/features/whitepaper... 
div will overview/features/whitepaper div will scroll and show...

My DIV Will work... but 2nd menu not fixed under my scroll.. how I slove it?

Check 2nd screenshot ... [Click to full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC4Ui.jpg)
[image: please open it full screen]

Here is my code example:

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
var poss = $('.inner-page-navs').offset().top;
var navs = $('.inner-page-navs');

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > poss) {
 navs.addClass("f-navs");
 (".inner-page-navs").fadeIn(3000);
 ('.inner-page-navs').addClass("f-navs");
} else {
 navs.removeClass("f-navs");
}
});
});

jQuery("document").ready(function($){
var pos = $('.inner-page-nav').offset().top;
var nav = $('.inner-page-nav');

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > pos) {
 nav.addClass("f-nav");
 (".inner-page-nav").fadeIn(3000);
 ('.inner-page-nav').addClass("f-nav");
} else {
 nav.removeClass("f-nav");
}
});
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $("a.scroll_to").click(function() {
   var target = $(this).attr("data-more-info");
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+target).offset().top - 50 }, "slow");
   return false;
 });
});
```

```css
html, body, div {padding:0;margin:0;}
.inner-page-navs{ background: #E5F6FE;}
.f-navs{ z-index: 2900; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;margin-top:0px;} /* this make our menu fixed top */
.page-nav-contents {height: 42px;margin: 0 auto;max-width: 1170px;width: 100%;}
.page-nav-contents ul { list-style: none;margin: 0; }
.page-nav-contents ul li{float: left; margin: 0px 2px; padding: 10px 70px !important;}
.navactive{background:#A1DDFF;}
.navactive a{color:#fff;}
.page-nav-contents ul li:hover{background:#A1DDFF;}
.page-nav-contents ul li:hover a{color:#fff;}
.page-nav-contents ul li a {font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;}
.page-nav-contents ul li a:hover {text-decoration:none;color:#fff;}
/** end 1st menu **/


.inner-page-nav{ background: #E5F6FE;}
.f-nav{ z-index: 99999; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;margin-top:60px;} /* this make our menu fixed top */
.f-nav .navOverview {margin-top:100px !important;}
.page-nav-content {height: 42px;margin: 0 auto;max-width: 1170px;width: 100%;}
.page-nav-content ul { list-style: none;margin: 0; }
.page-nav-content ul li{float: left; margin: 0px 2px; padding: 10px 70px !important;}
.navactive{background:#A1DDFF;}
.navactive a{color:#fff;}
.page-nav-content ul li:hover{background:#A1DDFF;}
.page-nav-content ul li:hover a{color:#fff;}
.page-nav-content ul li a {font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;}
.page-nav-content ul li a:hover {text-decoration:none;color:#fff;}
/** End 2nd menu **/

.clear{clear:both;}
.box{width:100%;height:350px;min-width:600px;padding:0;margin:0;}
.red{background:red;}
.green{background:green;}
.blue{background:blue;}
.grey{background:grey;}
.yellow{background:yellow;}


a.scroll_to{
    color:#f00;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inner-page-navs" class="inner-page-navs">
  <div class="page-nav-contents">
    <ul>
      <li class="navactive"><a href="#navhome" >Home</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#navservice" >Service</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#navsupport" >Support</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#navpricing" >Pricing</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box red"></div>
<div id="inner-page-nav" class="inner-page-nav">
  <div class="page-nav-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navOverview">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navFeatures">Features</a></li>
      <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navWhiteBro">Whitepaper & Brochure</a></li>
      <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navOrder">Order</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box green" id="navOverview"><h2>Overview</h2></div>
<div class="box blue" id="navFeatures"><h2>Features</h2></div>
<div class="box grey" id="navWhiteBro"><h2>Witepaper and Brochure</h2></div>
<div class="box yellow" id="navOrder"><h2>Order</h2></div>
```

Please don't give me minus. I really try hard to learn and make this.. but I'm unable to do it properly. Hope someone help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            jQuery("document").ready(function($){
            var poss = $('.inner-page-navs').offset().top;
            var navs = $('.inner-page-nav2').offset().top;;

            $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > navs) {

                $('.inner-page-nav2').addClass("f-navs");
                $(".inner-page-nav").fadeIn(3000);
                $('.inner-page-nav2').addClass("f-navs");
            } else {
                $('.inner-page-nav2').removeClass("f-navs");
            }
            });
            });

            jQuery("document").ready(function($){
            var pos = $('.inner-page-nav').offset().top;
            var nav = $('.inner-page-nav2');

            $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > pos) {
                nav.addClass("f-nav");
                (".inner-page-nav").fadeIn(3000);
                ('.inner-page-nav2').addClass("f-nav");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("f-nav");
            }
            });
            });

            $(window).load(function(){
                $("a.scroll_to").click(function() {
                  var target = $(this).attr("data-more-info");
                  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+target).offset().top - 50 }, "slow");
                  return false;
                });
            });

            <div id="inner-page-navs" class="inner-page-navs">
              <div class="page-nav-contents">
                <ul>
                  <li class="navactive"><a href="#navhome" >Home</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#navservice" >Service</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#navsupport" >Support</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#navpricing" >Pricing</a></li>
                </ul>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box red"></div>
            <div id="inner-page-nav" class="inner-page-nav2">
              <div class="page-nav-content">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navOverview">Overview</a></li>
                  <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navFeatures">Features</a></li>
                  <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navWhiteBro">Whitepaper & Brochure</a></li>
                  <li><a class="scroll_to" data-more-info="navOrder">Order</a></li>
                </ul>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box green" id="navOverview"><h2>Overview</h2></div>
            <div class="box blue" id="navFeatures"><h2>Features</h2></div>
            <div class="box grey" id="navWhiteBro"><h2>Witepaper and Brochure</h2></div>
            <div class="box yellow" id="navOrder"><h2>Order</h2></div>
```

Comment: Thak you so much for your help.... but I need both menu fixed in header when scroll... there is only fixed one menu... please check my 1st and 2nd screenshot.

Comment: That's great :)
but when I click overview there is show some problem..  and when I click Features .. menu will scroll to top.. and Features come .. but Features some space automatically hide inside menu... please check... http://prntscr.com/7hmenl its Overview problem..

http://prntscr.com/7hmesy and its features div problem.. there hide some space under menu...

Comment: and the first manu scroll not working. try to update to you. let me know if once you completed

Comment: That's great :) but when I click overview there is show some problem.. and when I click Features .. menu will scroll to top.. and Features come .. but Features some space automatically hide inside menu... please check... prntscr.com/7hmenl its Overview problem.. prntscr.com/7hmesy and its features div problem.. there hide some space under menu...

Comment: are you trying to set css like padding-top or margin-top?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80682/discussion-between-vel-and-nodiv-noclass).

Comment: at last I solved this problem. using top - 120 in scroll to top js...

>> scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 60 }, 2000); <<

Your code help me lot.

Thank you for your great help :)

Comment: :) really you have a sweet heart...  Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: I posted another problem here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892300/change-list-class-on-click-or-scroll-div
...  if you are free, hope you'll help me.